# Adjective order/plural form of "ninety", "story/stories", and "tall."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, adjectives, measure-expressions, adjective-order

I was doing some multiple choice exercises. One of them was:-

> A fire in the ..... building could be a problem for firefighters
>
> 1- Ninety-story-tall
>
> 2-ninety-tall-story
>
> 3-ninety-stories-tall
>
> 4-ninety stories

I wonder, why does 1 work but not 2? What does the sentence mean when we use 1?

Comment: Why do you believe option 2 could be correct? What would be the meaning of sentence 2, in your opinion? What would be the meaning of sentence 1, in your opinion?

Comment: @CopperKettle, I don't think that 2 is correct. When I was solving the exercise, I could not figure our the intended meaning and so I couldn't differentiate them. Now as I understand the meaning of 1, I know why it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase"ninety-story" is a noun phrase. More importantly, it is a measure phrase. We often use measure phrases like this to modify adjectives. The measure phrase always comes ***before*** the adjective. Usually, the measure phrase is made from a number and a unit of measurement (a noun). The unit of measurement often measures time or space, but it could be anything:

- **ten-mile**-long
- **five-year**-old
- **three-metre**-wide
- **ninety-storey**-tall

These big phrases are adjective phrases. When they come before a noun, the unit of measurement is singular and we use hyphens to join up the words. When they don't have a following noun, for example if they appear after the verb BE, then the unit of measurement can be plural and 
we don't need hyphens:

- The island was **ten miles long**

Comment: An example of a non space/time measure phrase is a forty-person theater.

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is *ninety-story tall*.

*Tall* is an adjective that modifies *building*.

*Ninety-story* is an adverb that modifies *tall*.

*Ninety-tall story* doesn't make sense because you are selecting modifiers that qualify how tall the building is, not how tall any story is.  *Story* also is not typically an adjective so it is confusing for that reason too.

*Ninety-stories* and *ninety-stories tall* are wrong because only nouns have plural forms in English.  Adjectives/adverbs do not.  So "ninety-stories" tall sounds like an additional noun for a brief moment until the speaker/reader gets to the word "building" and figures out what you meant.

Incidentally, you could say:

> A fire in the ninety-story building could be a problem for firefighters

and that would be OK.